# Route all postfix mail through noreply@

Tags: postfix, lamp, email-server

I want postfix to send out all email via `noreply@mydomain.com`

My `main.cf` looks like

```
sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/canonical
local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all
```

and my `canonical` file looks like

```
/domain.local/ noreply@mydomain.com
```

Anybody know why this isn't working? I have already tried restarting the server.

I am not sure what the `/domain.local/` part does, as the content was motivated by a blog post.

Comment: Are you sure all your outgoing emails look like user@domain.local? Check /var/log/mail or /var/log/maillog file.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu I don't know what /domain.local/ means. A lot of my outgoing emails looks like uname321@yahoo.com . Basically I need to change the FROM field to be noreply@mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domain.local` is the pattern. When pattern matches an email address it is replaced with noreply@domain.com.

If you want everything replaced you can use `.*` as the pattern.